# Using row_number() over(partition by 1) gives inconsistent rownumbers within cte

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with nested `super` data in field `event_params`. I want to unfold to get a field then rejoin back onto the top level table. I tried using row_number() per the title but get inconsistent results, seems row_number() changes each time.

```
with
    
ga_raw as (
select
    row_number() over (partition by 1) as rn,
    user_pseudo_id,
    event_name,
    event_date,
    event_timestamp,
    event_params,
    device,
    traffic_source as user_attribution
from ga4_extract."daily-ga4-raw" as g
where event_date = '2022-10-24'
and lower(event_name) = 'trial'
),

get_event_id as (
select
    rn,
    t1.event_name,
    ep.value.string_value::varchar event_id
from ga_raw t1, t1.event_params ep
where ep.key::varchar = 'event_id'
)

select
    g.rn,
    e.event_id,
    g.event_name,
    g.event_date,
    g.user_attribution
from ga_raw g
join get_event_id e on g.rn = e.rn
```

Maybe there's a better way? All I want is to pull out event_params nested data point `event_id` and align it onto ga_raw. Is there a work around where I don't need to use cte `get_event_id`?

If keeping to my existing approach, which I've learned is flawed since rn (row_number()) returns different row numbers and rejoins onto incorrect rows. SInce there's no id for each row, is there another way to pull this nested data point up into it's own field on `ga_raw`?

[edit]
Sudo code illustration of what I wish I could do but cannot:

```
select
        field1,
        field2,
        ... etc...,
        case when event_params.key = "event_id" then event_params.value.string_value end as event_id,
    from ga4_extract."daily-ga4-raw" as g
    where event_date = '2022-10-24'
    and lower(event_name) = 'trial'
```

I attempted the above just as a long shot but got all nulls for event_id.

Comment: What do you mean with _"get inconsistent results, seems row_number() changes each time"_? Given you don't specify an `order by` in `over`, numbers won't have a specific order. Also, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve with that `partition by 1`.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel let me rephrase my question more generally here. I want to `select * from ga4_extract."daily-ga4-raw"` but 'pull up' event_params.value.string_value when event_params.key = "event_id". The result set would have the same number of rows as daily-ga4-raw, i.e. no unfolding leading to multiple rows.

Comment: You're other question, `what you're trying to achieve with that partition by 1` I am trying to create a row identifier on the daily-ga4-raw table so that I can unfold it, get my data point then roll it back up. Since there's no row id I tried to create one using row_number.